# can't recognize keytool-importkeypair

Tags: android, operating-system

I'm trying to release an android app with system privileges using the following link:

http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/apk-with-system-privileges/

my OS knowlage is somewhat poor and i cant get my system to recognize "keytool-importkeypair" as a command.

- I'm using Win ex.
- added the folder to the system PATH.
- started cmd as Admin.
- changed the keytool-importkeypair file to: exe,com and bat files, the system could recognize the file then, but still didnt do the right oporation.

May it be a file for linux only? i really don't know much about system command files, so any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

keytool-importkeypair is a Linux file. It will not work on Windows. To use this as a command on Linux:

1) Download the keytool-importkeypair from following location and save it to the same folder where platform certs are present

https://github.com/getfatday/keytool-importkeypair

2) Once the file is there, you can simply use it by typing

$./keytool-importkeypair "rest of the command"

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be a linux file.. just need to know how to add it to the linux path now.

Comment: Facing the same issue.Did you find the soln?

Answer (score 0):

just in case this is still useful for someone, you don't have to add it to the PATH, you can simple make the keytool-importkeypair file executable with
*chmod +x keytool-importkeypair*

and them simple *./keytool-importkeypair [rest of your command]*